# debugging android application line by line in eclipse

Tags: android, debugging

could you please tell me how to debug an android application line by line in eclipse ? 
It is quite complicated , I have searched a lot but couldn't find anything useful . Thanks from now .

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: From this above link try to Debug as->Android Applications instead of Debug as->Java applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a breakpoint at first line in the first class(right click on the line and select Toogle breakpoint), than run appli in debug mode (Run->Debug).
It will stop at your breakpoint and then use F6 to navigate line by line. (keep mouse on the desired variable and it will show the value at that point or even add in expressions to see the value every time)

Comment: thank you so much , i have tried what you said but i have a problem. the green point should be in the below line everytime i have pressed f6 button , doesn't it? but i cant understand if im in the next line :(

Comment: would you please explain again , cause I don't understand :(

Comment: forgive my inexperience in this field :(

Comment: no problem, do you work in eclipse?

Comment: in eclipse, I have the row at which I am in debug selected with green color....I don't have a green point :(

Comment: the green points are the breakpoints , arent they ? i mean everytime i move to next line , that breakpoint should move to that line ,too . Right ?

Comment: no, the breakpoint remains where you have put it in the first place. just the selected row should change after pressing F6.

Comment: i dont have a green row, i dont know what to do... :(

Comment: can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pause the execution and analyse the variable's values at runtime , if that's what you are trying to do.

you could add logs after every line, and track the values of the variables you are trying to "watch" in the logcat.

Comment: We can use break points to pause the execution and "watch" the current values of the variables. Right?

Comment: i have already tried it but i cant debug it line by line